# use a standard deck of cards to determine the probabilities.

Tags: probability

$1$. P(face card and a $5$ without replacement)=?
$2$. P(numerical card less than $5$ and then a king with replacement)=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) $\frac{16}{52}*\frac{4}{52}$
There are 4 cards less than 5 which each have 4 types of them, making it 16. Since the card is replaced, the number being divided by stays 52. There are 52 cards in a deck.

Comment: a 5 picked first then a face card .

Comment: In that case $\frac{4}{52}*\frac{12}{51}$ , because you are taking one card away. If you meant the other way around, just switch the 51 and 52. By the way, the other answer is including 2 jokers, however, it is a good hint!

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Bayes Theorem applies.  $P(A)P(B\mid A) = P(B)P(A \mid B)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, you are absolutely right, my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
How many face cards are in a deck?
How many $5$'s are in a deck?
How many $4$'s, $3$'s, $2$'s, and $1$'s in a deck?
How many kings in a deck?
The probability of each occurring is $\frac{The \space number \space of \space the \space certain \space type \space of \space card \space in \space a \space deck}{The \space number \space of \space cards \space in \space a \space deck \space (54)}$
The probability of one occurring after another is the $2$ probabilities multiplied together.

Answer (score 0):

1) There are 12 face cards in a pack (Jack, Queen, King of four suits), and likewise four 5's. When drawing without replacement the events are *dependent*.

Assuming you are drawing just two cards, then: $$P(\mbox{Face} \cap \mbox{Five}) = P(\mbox{Face}) \times P(\mbox{Five}\mid\mbox{Face}) = \frac{12}{52}\times\frac{4}{51} = \frac{4}{221} $$

2) There are 16 cards less than five (this includes the aces).  When drawing with replacements (assuming shuffling after replacement) the drawings are *independent*.

$$ P(\mbox{LessThanFive} \cap \mbox{King}) = P(\mbox{LessThanFive})\times P(\mbox{King}) = \frac{16}{52}\times\frac{4}{52} = \frac{4}{169} $$